# wordpress contact form 7 - get_postet_data() with title

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a function which gets the posted data after a submitted contact form.

```
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
$posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
```

That works fine, but now, I want to get additional values. E.g. in my form:

```
[text* name-1]
```

I would like to get the value "name-1" in addition to the value which the user fill into the form. Any idea?

The result should be like: "name-1: Smith"

Thanks in advance for your help.

Greets, Yab

PS. I am using Wordpress 4.1.1 and CF7 4.1